# LIKE condition : why '%,x,' doesn't work but '%,x,%' works

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table called image

there is column called `category` in that table which varchar and stores all the categories of an image sperated with comma .

i one row i have :

```
category : ,26,25,
```

this query works fine

```
SELECT *
FROM `images`
WHERE `confirm` =1
AND `category` LIKE '%,25,%' AND `category` LIKE '%,26,%'
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

and i get all the rows with `,25,26,`  as their category

but

why this  doesn't work ?

```
SELECT *
FROM `images`
WHERE `confirm` =1
AND `category` LIKE '%,25,' AND `category` LIKE '%,26,'
LIMIT 0 , 20
```

Comment: Because `category LIKE '%,25,' AND category LIKE '%,26,'` is impossible.  You are asking for the string to end with two different values.

Comment: `'%,25,'` means "ends with".  `'%,25,%'` means "contains".

Comment: If you created a proper many-to-many structure you won't experience such an issue. I don't even mention that `LIKE '%...'` cannot be optimized and considered to be a bad practice

Comment: one of the basis of relational databases, is that a column shouldn't be used as an array. This is, it shouldn't contain multiples values. For that you should create a table of categories, and another table where you put rows for image-category pairs. besides, this is an "i-have-never-read-the-docs" question, since you dont know what a certain syntax does, and ask why it doesnt do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LIKE` matches the entire string. `LIKE '%,26,'` matches strings that *end* in `,26,`, not strings that *contain* it. You need `%` on both ends if you want to search for a substring anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`LIKE` must match the entire value in the table.  If there is content in the table after the "25,", then `LIKE '%,25,'` will not match it.

If you want regular expression matching in `mysql`, you can use `RLIKE`:

```
AND category RLIKE ',25,' AND category RLIKE ',26,'
```

but if you use `LIKE`, you have to match the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The `like` is an *exact* match, not a match for something arbitrarily inside the string.  You need wildcards to say that you want a match somewhere inside.

The expressions:

```
AND `category` LIKE '%,25,' AND `category` LIKE '%,26,'
```

Are looking for cases when `category` ends in ',25,' AND ends in ',26,' at the same time.  Clearly, this is not possible.

You can also phrase this in MySQL as:

```
AND find_in_set(25, category) > 0 and find_in_set(26, category) > 0
```

Also, you should have a separate table that has one row per category.  Such queries would be much easier and more efficient with a proper relational data structure.